# Mysql Add value to Float datatype

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update balance of user based on no of shares(count) they have in share table multiflying with 0.10 For this I have written following statement.I wonder! it is working perfect in sql but whenever i am trying it to mysql it works first time whenever user balance is zero but after that it doesn't work or add value.In mysql i am using float datatype in balance table.Below is my statement.

```
update `balance` 
set `Balance`='Balance'+(select COUNT(*) from `share` 
where `user` = `balance`.`User` and `status`='Active')*'.10'
```

Comment: Incidentally, balances are often related to money. Money is why the DECIMAL data type was invented

Answer (score 0):

I have found my answer. It is actually the comma between `balance` is doing the problem.

Below is my working code:

```sql
UPDATE `balance` 
SET `Balance` = Balance + (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `share`
    WHERE `user` = `balance`.`User` AND `status`='Active'
) * '.10'
```

Comment: I guess you mean 'inverted comma'